# How can I reset the variable to count from start again when I input new value?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. 
I decide to make a small game with things that I have been taught.
The rule is simple. I just need to console.log how many same value that I input, compare to the value that a computer generates randomly.
And the number of value goes back to 0, when I input a new value.
For example, a computer generates the value '495'. 
when I input '501', computer shows the result '1 hello' because both value has same value '5'. and when I input '154', computer shows the result '2 hello' because both have values '5' and '4'.

here is the code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>hello counting </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.scss">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>hello count</h1>
<form class="game-form">
    <input type="text" name='game1' class='number-input'>
    <input type="text" name='game2' class='number-input'>
    <input type="text" name='game3' class='number-input'>
    <button class="add">add</button>
</form>
  <ul class="game-list"></ul>
</div>
</body>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const gameFormEl = document.querySelector(".game-form");
const gameListEl = document.querySelector(".game-list");
let gameArr = [];

gameFormEl.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  addNum(
    e.target.elements.game1.value,
    e.target.elements.game2.value,
    e.target.elements.game3.value
  );
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.reset();
});

// computer generated random number
const shuffle = () => {

  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  const container = [];
  let container2 = [];
  const arrLeng = arr.length; 
  for (let i = 0; i < arrLeng; i++) {
    arrSplice = arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
    container.push(Number(arrSplice));
  }
  // pick first three number that generates randomly
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    container2 = container2.concat(container[j]);
  }
   // because player input number is string format
  return container2.join("");
};
shuffle();


const ranComNum = shuffle();

 // players random input number
const addNum = (a, b, c) => {
  let numAdd = a + b + c;
  const gameItemEl = document.createElement("li");
  gameItemEl.textContent = numAdd;

  // pushing strings into numAdd array 
  gameArr.push(numAdd);

  console.log(ranComNum);

  // hello function 
  const hello = () => {
   var helloCounter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < gameArr.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
          if (ranComNum[i] === gameArr[j][k]) {
           helloCounter++;
         }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(`${helloCounter} hello`);
   };
  hello()
};
```

I almost complete the code except one thing. 
I tried but I don't know how to the variable(helloCounter) counts the value from 0 again when I input a new value. It maintains the value that counts before and keeps adding when I input a new value.
Should I create new function for counting hello outside of addNum function?

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to see how many common characters are in both strings? When is it supposed to reset the value? After every new number generation? Is there a reason you're not making the randomly generated number as one 3 digit number and then splicing that (though you don't need to unless comparing)?

Comment: yes you are right. I want to compare common characters of both strings and the value of helloCounter has to be reset after I input the string value which means when I hit 'add' button.
About splicing the arr array... that is what I came up with... there must be a better way to generate number as one 3 digit number but I will figure it out after I solve the variable reset issue

Answer (score 0):

All right, firstly, move the script into the body, it should be in the footer within the body.

Secondly, it would be better to generate the numbers randomly:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min +1) + Min);`
so
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (999 - 100 + 1) + 100);`

Thirdly, you're using let which is strict redeclaration, so you can't redeclare the variable. Try it with `var helloCounter = 0` instead

Comment: I declared the variable using var instead of let but does not work either. It does not reset the value back to 0

Comment: Would you mind posting the full HTML? I'd like to test it. At the very least, your line 27 in the js doesn't work as you're assigning a value to a constant after declaration.

Comment: I found out where the issue is coming from... actually the variable helloCounter is reset when I inputs new value but I push into every new input into gameArr.